# Jhipster - Error while starting a jhipster mysql project

Tags: jhipster

I am trying jhipster and ran into the following error while starting the application which is configured to use mysql as the backend:

Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The applicationcannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: [dev]

I have the database created and mysql is up and running at the right ports

From troubleshooting this in my IDE, it appears that the datasource properties are null while trying to configure liquibase.

My application-dev.yml

server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    profiles: dev

```
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    databaseName:test
    serverName:localhost
    username: admin
    password:  xxxxx
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true

jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
```

Any thoughts on what should I try next to get past this erorr?

Comment: Can you verify that it is reading in your application-dev.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should write the database name in the url AND in the databaseName properties.

-> can you remove the databaseName configuration and see what happens?

Otherwise, please send the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, it may be that the source folders configuration is wrong. When I imported the project, for some reason the src/main/resources and src/test/resources folders had all files excluded.

Check your build path and make sure all files are included.